# Сохранение отредактированного текста в файл

Tags: c#

Как отредактированный текст(курсив, подчеркнутый и тд) из richtextbox сохранить в текстовый файл ?
Пробовал через savefile, но что-то не вышло.

```
 SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(dialog.FileName ,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
```

Comment: уберите строку `dialog.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Убрал. Не сохраняет всё равно.

Comment: А я говорю - сохраняет.

Comment: Я, наверное, не так выразился. Мне нужно, чтобы он сохранял текст, который написан жирным шрифтом, курсивом и тд. Проблемы он сохраняет.

Comment: `richTextBox1.SaveFile(dialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`

Comment: может дело в типе? PlainText это насколько я понимаю текст без html.

Comment: Да, дело было в plainrext. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  richTextBox1.SaveFile(dialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```